# Rails Optional Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to implement optional nested resourcing in my rails app. I have an existing resource, Projects. I would like them to remain standalone but also have the option to nest or 'group' them under a Project Group. I've done nested resources before, but I'm not sure how I would approach nesting them *after* they've been created. Is this possible or would I need to take a different approach?

EDIT:

For clarity to anyone else who might stumble upon this, I've decided to go for an optional, `many_to_many` approach. This way, `Projects` can be created standalone, but can also be added to a `Project_Group`. I'm planning on doing this through a connection model. So it will be set up like this:

```
Project has_many_project_groups, through: :groups
Project_Group has_many_projects, through: :groups
```

and

```
Group belongs_to :project, optional: true
Group belongs_to :project_group, optional: true
```

Will keep updated as I go along

Comment: I've answered your question but you have not shown any code whatsoever to be fixed, you will likely have your question closed as showing not enough effort to solve your own problem or not enough details

Comment: Can I not use SO in the ideation stage of developing? It's conceptual at this point, and the usual code I know works for regular nesting would not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about nesting your routes or nesting your folder structure or both? You could achieve this through routes with a product route and a group route with a product route nested inside the group route

```
resources :products
resources :groups do
  resources :products
end
```

You can set paths to the various controllers within the resources declarations if you wish to use different product controllers (one nested and one not) and then if you attach a product to a group with a `belongs_to group` in your product model it would then be accessible to the group assuming you have a corresponding `has_many products`
you would have to set the relationships as optional so do not enforce referential integrity in your database.
Can't really offer any further advice as you have not shown what you have actually tried to do and what has failed so that's it really.

Comment: I guess it's figuring out how to manage the relationship. It needs to be a child but also independent. So would using `belongs_to, optional: true` for the Project be the way to go about it?

Comment: @LJ-03 YTes that would solve your problem. You will likely run into problems and you may well find that a default group is what is needed